# fscanf() function puts a \000 at the first char read

Tags: c

Im trying to read a file with this format:

```
05874121 A 7
07894544 C 3
05655454 B 5
05879544 B 6
05763465 C 2
```

and assign each 'word' to different variables (dni, model, trash)

This code is running on Linux, and I use CLion for debugging.

```
char *path = "file.txt";
FILE *f;
int result;
char dni[9], model[1], trash[100];

f = fopen(path, "r");
do {
    result = fscanf(f, "%s %s %s", dni, model, trash);
    printf("DNI: %s\n", dni);
}
while( result > 0);

fclose(f);
```

This should print the first column values, but when I execute the program, the output is just:
"DNI: "
"DNI: "
"DNI: "
... and so on.

While debugging, I realized that "dni" store correctly all the numbers (as chars), but the very first element, dni[0], is always: 0 '/000'
like if it was the end of the string.

I dont know why is happening this.

Comment: How many bytes does a `\0`-terminated string with the value `"C"` contain?

Comment: You need to allocate space for the terminating `'\0'` character in each of your strings.  In the case of `model`, you have allocated a single character, which means you can only safely store a zero-length string plus the null terminator.  So you have a memory corruption problem.

Comment: The need for ***null-terminated** byte strings* to contain space for the terminator as well as the string data itself should have been taught in just about any book, tutorial or class. If it isn't then you need to change book, tutorial or not skip class.

Comment: Try `model[1]` --> `model[2]` and `"%s %s %s"` --> `"%8s %1s %99s"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did 2 corrections in your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
        char *path = "file.txt";
        FILE *f;
        int result;
        char dni[9], model[2], trash[100];

        f = fopen(path, "r");
        while(1) {
            result = fscanf(f, "%s %s %s", dni, model, trash);
            if (result < 1) break;
            printf("DNI: %s model %s trash %s\n", dni, model, trash);
        }

        fclose(f);
        return 0;
}
```

First, the variable model[2] must have an extra character for the end of the string.

Then, the line "if (result <1) break;".

Probably, the error was the model[1] with only one character. The \ 000 in dni can be the end of the model string.

Comment: The problem is solved by adding an extra charecter to model variable, thank you!